# loops to store data in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe, time-series

I have long scripts used in order to create some process.

```
xm <- 1 
produccion_tx <- data.frame(produccion_mes_mes[xm])  # Creates the table in a df
source("4_WMIN.R")  # makes the maths
source("5_WMIN.R")  # export an excel file
source("6_WMIN.R")  # saves the data
mes_t1 <- mylist

xm <- 2 
produccion_tx <- data.frame(produccion_mes_mes[xm])  # Creates the table in a df
source("4_WMIN.R")  # makes the maths
source("5_WMIN.R")  # export an excel file
source("6_WMIN.R")  # saves the data
mes_t2 <- mylist
```

....and so on.

I would like to store all these data in objects called: mes_t1, mes_t2, and so on.

```
for (xm in 1:37) {
  produccion_tx  <-  data.frame(produccion_mes_mes[xm])  # Creates the table in a df
source("4_WMIN.R")# makes the maths
source("5_WMIN.R")#export an excel file
source("6_WMIN.R")# saves the data
  mes_t%s <- mylist #the results are in mylist
}
```

How can I save the table in each loop with a name like mes_t1, mes_t2, mes_t3... etc?

Comment: You can use `assign`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `assign`

```
for (xm in 1:37) {
    i = 1
    # do some stuff
    assign(paste0('mes_t', i), mylist)
    i = i + 1
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `assign`, I would store the results in a list(of lists). Something like `result <- list()/for(...)/result[[paste0('mes_t', i)]] <- mylist`.

Comment: I never use `assign` myself, and in this scenario would use a named list. However, OP asked for *objects* with the given names.

Comment: yes, I had noticed that, but I don't see a reason why he should do that, so I tried to give a more sensible suggestion. Many inexperienced R users make that mistake and the standard way of solving it is to use a list.